# Change default value for Job Activity Monitor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, ssms, sql-server-agent

Is there a way for me to programmatically (some configuration setting in a table / registry entry etc, I'm hoping) change the default value in the Auto Refresh setting to 5 seconds instead of 60, and to set the Auto Refresh to ON?

I need a way to make this a permanent setting - hopefully so that it applies to all users of the server.

> [image: Here I fixed your screen shot]

Comment: Try looking at below settings and play on stage:

Comment: Go to registry on your SQL Server machine and go to following.
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\ MSSQL11.YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME\SQLServerAgent

Comment: If I am managing a server with that many jobs I would not be using Job Activity Monitor...I like to use Idera's Job Manager (free by the way), much more efficient and believe you can set the auto refresh: https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/freetools/sqljobmanager

Comment: @TheGameiswar anything under that registry for `SQLServerAgent` is dealing with the SQL Server service on the server itself, it has nothing to do with an installation of SSMS on a desktop.